# p5 canvas with a defined field

Tags: p5.js

I wish to define a scalar field on the p5 canvas: which means essentially that each (x, y) => c, i.e. maps to some value c. I have already created this map. Take for example: a brightness field. I want to associate with each (x, y) a brightness value ranging from 0 to 255.

The goal: When I draw something on the canvas (say a line, or an ellipse) the colour of the object locally will be derived from my defined scalar field. Say, my ellipse covers the coordinates (10, 10) and (20, 20). In my definition of the field, (10, 10) => 240, (20, 20) => 22. Then the result is that the (20, 20) point of the ellipse will appear much darker than the (10, 10) point, the local brightness being exactly given by my map.

It would be helpful if I could get an insight so as to where I must start. I'm lost. I want to do this efficiently.

Comment: I think you would need to make your own ellipse function since you would be needing to modify individual pixels. First you would find all the pixels that the ellipse would cover, and then for each of those pixels, calculate the brightness levels, and then place those pixels on the canvas at their brightness levels.

Comment: My understanding is that it's what you can use shaders for, but this is less straight-forward than "regular" processing code. The processing website has [a pretty complete tutorial about shader](https://processing.org/tutorials/pshader/) and you can use them in p5js (see [`loadShader()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/loadShader) ). This could give you the efficiency you're looking for at the cost of the complexity of working with shaders. [The book of shaders](https://thebookofshaders.com/) is also a great resource to get started

Comment: @Samathingamajig That unfortunately would not be what I'm looking for, since it would involve changing each object separately!